# Android cUrl api

Tags: java, android, json

i am new to programming in android, i wanted to get json data from the website https://api.clashofclans.com/v1/clans in my android app.
How can i request the data in json format
curl -X GET --header 'Accept: application/json' --header "authorization: Bearer " 'https://api.clashofclans.com/v1/clans' .
i dont know how to add api key in the combination and open network connection. thanks in advance.

```
    urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        urlConnection.setReadTimeout(10000 /* milliseconds */);
        urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);
        urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        urlConnection.addRequestProperty("Accept","application/json");
        urlConnection.addRequestProperty("authorization","my api-key here");
        urlConnection.connect();

        // If the request was successful (response code 200),
        // then read the input stream and parse the response.
        if (urlConnection.getResponseCode() == 200) {
            inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            jsonResponse = readFromStream(inputStream);
        } else {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error response code: " + 
        urlConnection.getResponseCode());
        }
```

i am getting "Error response code: 403", can u tell me where my code is wrong
the api key is based on ip address.

Comment: Did you get any conclusion with that? I have the same issue: curl works fine with authorization but http api returns 403. BTW, why did you get a -1 on the question!?!

Comment: i dont know about the -1,,, but the solution below did work after some changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im sending it to my method this is where i return it as String:

```
public void getJson() {
    String json = getJSONFromURLConnection("https://api.clashofclans.com/v1/clans?name=illuminati");
    if (json != null) {
        Log.i("JSON", json.toString());
    }
}
```

Here getting all info:

```
  private String getJSONFromURLConnection(String urlString) {
    BufferedReader reader = null;

    try {
        URL url = new URL(urlString);
        urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        String apikey = YOUR_KEY;
        urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        urlConnection.addRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer " + apikey);
        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");

        if (urlConnection.getResponseCode() == 200) {
            InputStream stream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));

            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

            String line;

            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                buffer.append(line);
            }

            return buffer.toString();
        } else {
            Log.e("Error", "Error response code: " +
                    urlConnection.getResponseCode());
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (urlConnection != null)
            urlConnection.disconnect();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Created and tested, works for me hope you get the result you need.

Comment: where to add the api key for authorization?

Comment: at "connection" you can set properties like: connection.addRequestProperty("x-api-key", apiKey);

Comment: i have edited my code can u tell me where i am wrong.

Comment: 1. is my code correct.   2. i am getting 403 error which means "Access denied, either because of missing/incorrect credentials or used API token does not grant access to the requested resource."                                                    3. can check the documentation by logging in to this website or i can send a  screenshot.     https://developer.clashofclans.com

Comment: I can't White list My ip for some reason, try the link directly maybe you get the same error. Then contact the support

Comment: in the documentation i am given this block of code               " curl -X GET --header 'Accept: application/json' --header "authorization: Bearer <API token>" 'https://api.clashofclans.com/v1/clans?name=illuminati'    "

Comment: @rohit Sorry for the late response, check my update of code, this works for me. Remember to run it async and not in main thread.